Opengl Color Alpha is not working
Hi iam follwoing the cherno Game Dev series but with 3D Engine in mind iam at point where i cant figure out why is the alpha of the color not being affect when i try to change the alpha color texture alpha blending and all works fine but not the simple Red Color Quad alpha
//vertex
#type vertex
#version 330 core

layout(location = 0) in vec3 aPosition;//glVertexAttribPointer first parameter
layout(location = 1) in vec4 aColor;
layout(location = 2) in vec2 aTexCoord;
layout(location = 3) in float aTexIndex;
layout(location = 4) in float aTilingFactor;

out vec2 vTexCoord; //  also know as varrying
out vec4 vColor;
out float vTexIndex;
out float vTilingFactor;

uniform mat4 uModel;
uniform mat4 uView;
uniform mat4 uProjection;

void main()
{
    vColor = aColor;
    vTexCoord = aTexCoord;
    vTexIndex = aTexIndex;
    vTilingFactor = aTilingFactor;
    gl_Position = uProjection * uView * vec4(aPosition, 1.0);
}

//fragment
#type fragment
#version 330 core

layout(location = 0) out vec4 color;

in vec2 vTexCoord;
in vec4 vColor;
in float vTexIndex;
in float vTilingFactor;

uniform vec4 uColor;
uniform float uTilingFactor;
uniform sampler2D uTexture[32];

void main()
{
    color = texture(uTexture[int(vTexIndex)], vTexCoord * vTilingFactor) * vColor;
}

the Draw Quad function

{
        sData.QuadVertexPositions[0] = { 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f };
        sData.QuadVertexPositions[1] = { -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f };
        sData.QuadVertexPositions[2] = { -0.5f,-0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f };
        sData.QuadVertexPositions[3] = { 0.5f,-0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f };
}
void QuadRenderer::DrawQuad(const glm::vec3& position, const glm::vec3& size, const glm::vec4& color)
{
    if (sData.QuadIndexCount >= RendererData::MaxIndices)
    {
        FlushAndReset();
    }
    constexpr float tilingFactor = 1.0f;
    glm::mat4 transform = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f), position) * glm::scale(glm::mat4(1.0f), { size.x, size.y, size.z });

    constexpr size_t quadVertexCount = 4;
    constexpr glm::vec2 textureCoords[] = {
    { 1.0f, 0.0f },
    { 0.0f, 0.0f },
    { 0.0f, 1.0f },
    { 1.0f, 1.0f } 
    };
    float textureIndex = 0.0f;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < quadVertexCount; i++)
    {
        sData.QuadVertexBufferPtr->Position = transform * sData.QuadVertexPositions[i];
        sData.QuadVertexBufferPtr->Color = color;
        sData.QuadVertexBufferPtr->TexCoord = textureCoords[i];
        sData.QuadVertexBufferPtr->TexIndex = textureIndex;
        sData.QuadVertexBufferPtr->TilingFactor = tilingFactor;
        sData.QuadVertexBufferPtr++;
    }

    sData.QuadIndexCount += 6;

    sData.Stats.QuadCount++;
}

calling from sandbox

        QuadRenderer::DrawRotatedQuad({ 1.0f, -0.0f, 0.1f },45.0f, { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f },{  0.8f, 0.8f, 0.3f, 1.0f });
        QuadRenderer::DrawQuad({ -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f }, { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f }, { 0.8f, 0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f });
        QuadRenderer::DrawQuad({ 0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f }, { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f }, { mSquareColor });
        QuadRenderer::DrawQuad({ 0.0f, -0.0f, -0.1f }, { 10.0f, 10.0f, 1.0f }, mQuadTexture, 10.0f, { 0.8f, 0.2f, 0.3f, 0.2f });
        QuadRenderer::DrawRotatedQuad({mLocation }, rotation, { 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f }, mCubeTexture, 2.0f);

i have tried adding glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_COLOR, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_COLOR); which works but the colors are very very dim, very thing else fails, please correct me on what am i missing
